# Line height of span does not line up vertically

Tags: css

[image]

I've got a button with a span in it.

```css
.ExpandButton {
  border: 2px solid #440099;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #7d4eb8;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-right: 32px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ExpandButton"><span>More Actions</span></div>
```

I can't figure out why the text is not aligning to it's own span container.

I've obviously tried using flex and align-center but with no luck. The issue is within the span not aligning vertically to it's container.

Comment: as i see so far i think it is caused by the padding-right property in the .ExpandButton CSS class. The padding-right value of 32px is pushing the text inside the span element to the right .
try 

   `.ExpandButton {
        border: 2px solid #440099;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 600;
        letter-spacing: 0.02em;
        color: #7d4eb8;
        line-height: 1;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

For the **parent container of text** try to give,

```
display:"flex";
align-items:"center";
```

***Your code will be looks like,***

```
.ExpandButton {
  border: 2px solid #440099;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #7d4eb8;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-right: 32px;

  display:"flex";
  align-items:"center";
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

- 

> `display:"flex"` , `align-items:"center"` aligns your item center in vertical direction

- 